# Visual Studio Code: Markdown: How can I enclose a highlighted word with backticks?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I select a word (e.g. by double-clicking on the word) in order to then enclose it with backticks, the word is deleted as soon as I type a backtick, and only when I press Cmd+z do I get the desired effect. How can I avoid the Cmd+z and when pressing backtick directly get the word wrapped with backticks? I use a Mac and a German keyboard.

Comment: Strange, I am able to do the same, without doing any such thing. I just double-click on the word and then press the backtick key, and there you go. This is the default setting.

Comment: By default this setting is language specific - for me it works as expected for markdown, but not in C#. Maybe double check that VSCode definitely thinks you're writing markdown (look at bottom right corner, should say what it thinks it is). If you want to make it always on rather than lang specific, check out the setting `Editor: Auto Surround`